# Calculating transform-origin of two overlapping elements

Tags: css-transforms, getboundingclientrect

I have an image (represented as green) overlaying a box (represented as blue), and the image is going to be `transform: scale()`ing in size. When this happens I need all edges of the image to complete their transformation at the same time.

To do this I need to calculate the `transform-origin` based on where the image is located overtop of the bounding box, using JavaScript. Assume I know all the coordinates that `getBoundingClientRect()` provides, for both elements.

In the six examples below I’ve placed a red dot where the transform-origin percentages should intersect.

I just can’t figure out the math to get there. The closest I've come to finding an answer is with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837655/calculate-transform-origin-from-original-and-scaled-boxes), but it's a little vague and I'm not sure I fully understand the answer itself. I would greatly appreciate help with this, and will happily provide more details if I'm missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around, I figured out the formula is:

```
(
  (box.left - image.left) /
  (image.width - box.width)
) * 100
```